# From Canada, can re-enter the US using the valid DS-2019?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, j1-visas

My US VISA expired but I have my 2019 valid for more 6 months. Can I go to Canada (for about a week) and re-enter the US using the valid DS-2019?

Comment: When does your current I-94 expire?

Comment: @Doc OP is on a J1 visa, so if the DS-2019 is valid, so is the I-94

Answer (score 1):

If you're not a national of Cuba, Iran, Sudan or Syria, then yes, you can visit Canada, Mexico or the Caribbean for max 30 days and re-enter the US with your passport and valid DS-2019.